# Show Multiple Locations near to Current Location on Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

Below is my class which draws an image on the current location on the google map. I need to draw two more locations on the google map. Suppose Point A has these values-

```
lat1: 37.33774833333334 
long1: -121.88670166666667
```

Point B has these values-

```
lat2: 37.336453 
long2: -121.884985
```

I need to draw Point A and Point B on the google map with an image. I already have images of those two points in my drawable folder.

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {    
    public static final String TAG = "GoogleMapsActivity";
    private MapView mapView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    Location location;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    CountDownTimer locationtimer;
    MapController mapController;
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();

 // Point A
   private Double lat1 = 37.33774833333334; 
   private Double long1 = -121.88670166666667 ;

// Point B              
   private Double lat2 = 37.336453;
   private Double long2 = -121.884985;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        try {       
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            initComponents();
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            mapView.setSatellite(false);
            mapController = mapView.getController();
            mapController.setZoom(15);
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (locationManager == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Location Manager Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return;
            }
            location = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (location == null)
                location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Location Are" + lat + ":" + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
                mapController.animateTo(point, new Message());
                mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
                List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                listOfOverlays.clear();
                listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
            }
            locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
                    location = l;
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                    if (l.getLatitude() == 0 || l.getLongitude() == 0) {
                    } else {
                        double lat = l.getLatitude();
                        double lng = l.getLongitude();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Location Are" + lat + ":" + lng,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            };
            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
            }
            locationtimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 5000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    if (location != null)
                        locationtimer.cancel();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    if (location == null) {
                    }
                }
            };
            locationtimer.start();          

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public MapView getMapView() {
        return this.mapView;
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
```

The Below class is the continuation from the above. In the below class I am showing my current location on the google map. So I think I need to make changes in this class only to show those two points also on the google map.

```
    class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
        private GeoPoint pointToDraw;

        public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
            pointToDraw = point;
        }

        public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
            return pointToDraw;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
                long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.current_user);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24, null);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated, how can I show two Points A and Point B on Google Map as well.

Comment: The answer in this topic may be helpful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573586/adding-itemizedoverlay-to-my-mapview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to draw Point A and Point B, but before you add this code check out this link and create the HelloItemizedOverlay class: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

```
HelloItemizedOverlay iOverlay1 = new ItemizedOverlay(R.drawable.pointAimage, MainActivity.this);
HelloItemizedOverlay iOverlay2 = new ItemizedOverlay(R.drawable.pointBimage, MainActivity.this);
GeoPoint pointA = new GeoPoint(37337748, -12188670);
GeoPoint pointB = new GeoPoint(37336453, -12188498);
OverlayItem overlayItemA = new OverlayItem(pointA, "Title", "Body");
OverlayItem overlayItemB = new OverlayItem(pointB, "Title", "Body");
iOverlay1.addOverlay(overlayItemA);
iOverlay2.addOverlay(overlayItemB);
```